# AWS EC2 instances with auto scaling staying in sync

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I have a Node.js web application currently running on a single EC2 instance on AWS. I am thinking of using auto scaling with 2 or more EC2 instances since the load on the application is increasing.

I have been trying to understand something with AWS Auto Scaling for a couple hours now but I cant seem to find an answer anywhere.

Currently, at many instances I SSH into my Ubuntu EC2 instance to modify some things or to run a deploy command (which grabs latest code from github). How does this work when you have, let's say 4 instances running under the auto scaling?

So if I SSH into a server and change the server.js file, what happens to the other 3 instances?

If that is not possible what are my choices? I have seen many people seeing that using S3 is the way to keep things in Sync but I don't fully get that. So I have to keep all my source code in S3 and do my edits from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to modify files directly on the server once they are in an auto-scaling group. Changing something on one server won't be reflected on the other servers, and even if you manually updated all the currently running servers, any servers added by auto-scaling actions will not have those changes.

There are many methods to solve this, for example using [AWS Code Deploy](https://aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/).

You could also configure something via an [EC2 User-Data script](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/execute-user-data-ec2/) in your auto-scaling configuration which will run on each server when they are created. That script could checkout the latest code from Git, or pull the latest build artifact from S3, and then start the app. When you have an update ready to deploy, you would simply flag the current instances as "unhealthy" and wait for the Auto-Scaling group to automatically replace them with new, updated instances.

Answer (score 0):

You could use AWS EFS to host your application code and all web servers will get content from EFS instead of individual server. This way you don't have to worry about modifying individual server content.

Comment: How can I add the efs settings on my auto-scaling-group-configuration, so that when new ec2 instance created, the efs will mount automatically with the new instance?

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do it is using github. you can update your code and push it to github and then terminate your existing instances and let the auto-scaling group spin up new instances with the updated code. here is a youtube tutorial video that has detailed steps on how to do it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lB3Ip0Yn-Zs

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, in order for the next user to understand your answer better. Also, provide a basic coverage of the content of your link, in case it stops working in the future.